# Bulk downloading Wikimedia Commons images from search query

Tags: images, wikimedia-commons

I am trying to understand how to bulk download Wikimedia Commons images, based on a search query (as in an artists name, as in my case "Michael Wolgemut").

Most of the resources I've been able to find seem to focus on downloading images based on Category, but this isn't going to work for me, as the images I want are spread over many categories. A search using the online interface ([link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?search=Michael%20Wolgemut&title=Special:MediaSearch&type=image)) gives me a collection of the images I want, with somewhere in the region of 2,700 results (not an unreasonable quantity to download).

However, I can't work out how to translate this kind of search into an API query. I tried the [commons-downloader](https://sr.ht/%7Enytpu/commons-downloader/) tool linked on the Wikimedia site, which only returned 277 images, and the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74495669/11002708) and [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13395), which were less helpful (I cannot untangle how to adapt them to my use case).

I'd like to limit the solution to bash and Python scripting, if possible, but that's not hugely important.

Also, if this can be done in such a way as to download the image descriptions as well, that would be excellent, but I'll settle for just the image files!